# Getting error while trying to rebuild a project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, appium

Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug] in project C:\AppiumProject

> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:clean
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDebug
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
> 2 files found with path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' from inputs:
> - C:\AppiumProject\app\libs\httpclient-4.5.5.jar
> - C:\AppiumProject\app\libs\httpcore-4.4.9.jar
> Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
> https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
> for more information

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s
24 actionable tasks: 23 executed, 1 up-to-date